# Spring Boot Schedule increment

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have one method for creating object. I put a schedule to create object on every second. In the object I have a parameter Time. Is it possible to increment the time on every created object. For example: 
First object time - 100000

Second object time - 103600

Third object - 107200

Fourth object - 110800

and etc

This is the method that i have

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${fixedDelay}", initialDelayString = "${initialDelay}")
public SomeObject createSomeObject() {
    SomeObject obj1 = new SomeObject();
    String epoch1 = Long.toString(Timestamp.valueOf(rf.getStartDate()).getTime() / 1000);
    time1= Long.valueOf(epoch1);
    obj1.setTime(time1);       
    list.add(obj1);   
    return obj1;   
}
```

In my case i want to increment the value of time1 for 3600 and every object to have bigger value for 3600 than the object before him.

Comment: Did you try to have a static variable in SomeObject class and every time you create an object increment it by whatever milliseconds you want? Then on the next object creation you can get that previous time since it's a static variable and there is only on instance of it for all the SomeObject instances.

Comment: Yes i have static variable in Pojo class of SomeObject, but like this the object in the list is without the Time parameter...

Answer (score 0):

To set the time as an instance variable:

```
final SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject();
someObject.setTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

If you need different units of time, convert accordingly with [TimeUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html).

For a static variable, you would want to call a setter method to set your class variable instead:

```
SomeObject.setTimeStamp(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Comment: For the time, I am setting some date in the application.properties. After that i am getting the value and converting in Unix TimeStamp and give that value in epoch1 variable. The point is that I want to increment that value for 3600 for the next object...

Comment: Then each time you call the method, simply set the variable to its own value plus 3600.

Comment: But like this when the object is added in the list it does not have the time parameter...

Comment: The whole problem is that the value of the config is constant... And I want that value to be on the first object... And after that to change it for 3600...